# How to add description when i click product in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I created simple shop store using php and mysql.

Here is my index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if(!empty($_GET["action"])) {
switch($_GET["action"]) {
    case "add":
        if(!empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
            $productByCode = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE code='" . $_GET["code"] . "'");
            $itemArray = array($productByCode[0]["code"]=>array('name'=>$productByCode[0]["name"], 'code'=>$productByCode[0]["code"], 'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'price'=>$productByCode[0]["price"]));

            if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                if(in_array($productByCode[0]["code"],$_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                    foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                            if($productByCode[0]["code"] == $k)
                                $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = $_POST["quantity"];
                    }
                } else {
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
            }
        }
    break;
    case "remove":
        if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
            foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                    if($_GET["code"] == $k)
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);              
                    if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
            }
        }
    break;
    case "empty":
        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
    break;  
}
}
?>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Simple PHP Shopping Cart</TITLE>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id="shopping-cart">
<div class="txt-heading">Shopping Cart <a id="btnEmpty" href="index.php?action=empty">Empty Cart</a></div>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_item"])){
    $item_total = 0;
?>  
<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th><strong>Name</strong></th>
<th><strong>Code</strong></th>
<th><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
<th><strong>Price</strong></th>
<th><strong>Action</strong></th>
</tr>   
<?php       
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item){
        ?>
                <tr>
                <td><strong><?php echo $item["name"]; ?></strong></td>
                <td><?php echo $item["code"]; ?></td>
                <td><input type="number" value="<?php echo $item["quantity"]; ?>"></td>
                <td align=right><?php echo "$".$item["price"]; ?></td>
                <td><a href="index.php?action=remove&code=<?php echo $item["code"]; ?>" class="btnRemoveAction">Remove Item</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
        $item_total += ($item["price"]*$item["quantity"]);
        }
        ?>

<tr>
<td colspan="5" align=right><strong>Total:</strong> <?php echo "$".$item_total; ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>    

  <?php
}
?>
<div class="checkout"> <a href="checkout.php?action=empty">Checkout</a></div>   

</div>

<div id="product-grid">
    <div class="txt-heading">Products</div>
    <?php
    $product_array = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tblproduct ORDER BY id ASC");
    if (!empty($product_array)) { 
        foreach($product_array as $key=>$value){
    ?>
        <div class="product-item"><a href="index.php?action=add&code=<?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]; ?>">
            <form method="post" action="index.php?action=add&code=<?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]; ?>">
            <div class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $product_array[$key]["image"]; ?>"></div>
            <div><strong><?php echo $product_array[$key]["name"]; ?></strong></div>
            <div class="product-price"><?php echo "$".$product_array[$key]["price"]; ?></div>
            <div><input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" /><input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btnAddAction" /></div>
            </form></a>
        </div>
    <?php
            }
    }
    ?>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

So, now working only add to cart button under the product.

I need to show description of product in separate page, when i click the each product box.

May i know, how can i do this? Thanks in advance.

Here is my product data in sql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblproduct` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` text NOT NULL,
  `price` double(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `product_code` (`code`)
);

INSERT INTO `tblproduct` (`id`, `name`, `code`, `image`, `price`) VALUES
(1, '3D Camera', '3DcAM01', 'product-images/camera.jpg', 1500.00),
(2, 'External Hard Drive', 'USB02', 'product-images/external-hard-drive.jpg', 800.00),
(3, 'Wrist Watch', 'wristWear03', 'product-images/watch.jpg', 300.00),
(4, 'Wrist Watch-8', 'wristWear', 'product-images/watch.jpg', 300.00),
(5, 'Shoes-by-Kobi-Levi', 'LegWear', 'product-images/Cat-Shoes-by-Kobi-Levi.png', 500.00);
```

Comment: Your question is a little confusing, could you describe it more clearly.

Comment: Simple. on each image create a link in which target will be _blank and send product id. on next page get description from database through this id and show.

Comment: There is insufficient information to answer your questions. Are your products stored in a database? What's your table structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you see most programmers handle this is as follows:

In your index.php you need to link to the detail page (detail.php)

```
<?php foreach ($_SESSION['cart_items'] as $item => data): ?>
    <a href="detail.php?id=<?= $item; ?>">Product</a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Then, on the detail.php page, you need to query for the product:

```
$productByCode = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE code='" . $_GET["code"] . "'");
```

Now you can simply echo the description from the query results:

```
Description: <?= $productByCode[0]['description']; ?>
```

**Note:** Taking a closer look at your table, I saw that it didn't contain a description column yet. You'll need to add this.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblproduct` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` text NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `price` double(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `product_code` (`code`)
);
```

Comment: Yes i have to add description.. I will check. thanks

Comment: Please, check my detail.php, is this right? <?php
$productByCode = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE code='" . $_GET["code"] . "'");
Description: <?= $productByCode[0]['description']; ?>
?>
I think, there is some mistake right? thanks

Comment: You should also close PHP after you do your query. Before the Destination: <?= ... ?> part